# Is it valid to combine a form POST with a query string?

Tags: http, post, query-string

I know that in most MVC frameworks, for example, both query string params and form params will be made available to the processing code, and usually merged into one set of params (often with POST taking precedence).  However, is it a valid thing to do according to the HTTP specification?  Say you were to POST to:

```
http://1.2.3.4/MyApplication/Books?bookCode=1234
```

... and submit some update like a change to the book name whose book code is 1234, you'd be wanting the processing code to take both the `bookCode` query string param into account, and the POSTed form params with the updated book information.  Is this valid, and is it a good idea?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is it valid according HTTP specifications ?

[Yes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Here is the general [syntax of URL as defined in those specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2)

```
http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
```

There is no additional constraints on the form of the http_URL. In particular, the [http method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9) (i.e. POST,GET,PUT,HEAD,...) used don't add any restriction on the http URL format.

When using the GET method : the server can consider that the request body is empty.

When using the POST method : the server must handle the request body.

> Is it a good idea ?

It depends what you need to do. I suggest you this [link](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html) explaining the ideas behind GET and POST.

I can think that in some situation it can be handy to always have some parameters like the user language in the *query* part of the url.

Comment: Just linking to the complete RFC is hardly helpfull in this case. Could you actually quote the relevant parts here?

Comment: There are no "relevant parts" as the spec does not address this specific question, i.e. the spec does not specifically state that a query string is allowed. Instead, the answer is reasonably inferred along precisely the lines given here, viz, that the specs for POST semantics say nothing to indicate that a query string is not allowed.

Comment: Indeed, a query string in a POST URI is perfectly legit. Nonetheless from a cursory look I could not find anything regarding precedence if you provide both a query string and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body in RFCs. The only thing I could find was what appears to be a sensible yet customary implementation-defined behaviour best described in [Go's net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm): *"Request body parameters take precedence over URL query string values in r.Form"*.

Comment: Barring some additional spec I could not find, the preceding widely observed behaviour could be a wrong assumption though as a server could apparently legitimately choose to interpret the query as applying to (or rather being part of) the resource being operated upon while the body applies to the sub-resource being e.g created by `POST`. Both could therefore contain an identically named key that would not collide since each one would be in the scope of a different entity.

Comment: The HTTP RFC-2616 has been obsoleted by new documents that udates the best practices an the internet and clarifies some point, in this RFC set however nothing seems to document and then disallow query parameters on request with the POST  method. In particular I found these points to be relevant : [RFC-7230 §2.1. Client/Server Messaging](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.1), [RFC-7230 §2.7. Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.7), [RFC-7231 §4.3.3. POST](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)

Comment: "Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the origin server"
For this use case, the query string is probably invalid since the query string "serves to identify a resource." You can't identify something that is yet to be identified. It's self-contradictory.

Comment: Maybe it is an interesting sidenote that it is **undefined behavior** in the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

*I know that in most MVC frameworks, for example, both query string params and form params will be made available to the processing code, and usually merged into one set of params (often with POST taking precedence).*

Any competent framework should support this.

*Is this valid*

Yes. The POST method in HTTP does not impose any restrictions on the URI used.

*is it a good idea?*

Obviously not, if the framework you are going to use is still clue-challenged.  Otherwise, it depends on what you want to accomplish.  The major use case (redirection of a data subset to a new POST target) has been [irretrievably broken by browser implementations](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html) (all mechanically following the broken lead of Mosaic/Netscape), so the considerations here are mostly theoretical.