# TradeOgre API always return "Invalid market"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use TradeOgre's API but I'm having some issues with POST datas. Here's the code:

```
router.get("/submitsell", async (req, res) => {
   var data = {
      market: "BTC-DOGE",
      quantity: 200,
      price: 0.00000074
   }

   try {
     const response = await fetch('https://{key:secret}@tradeogre.com/api/v1/order/buy', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
     })

     result = await response.json()
     res.status(200).send(result)
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return 0
   }
})
```

I spoke with the admin of the site and he told me that he thinks that POST parameters should be URLEncoded instead of JSON. I tried with "newdata = URLSearchParams(data).toString()" and got the same result.

I found some API codes for this site but I can't find the difference in how they send the datas to the site.

Here are links to these bots:

[TradeOgre Python API Wrapper](https://github.com/Endogen/TradeOgrePy)

[pollodigomma tradeogre-api](https://github.com/pollodigomma/tradeogre-api)

EDITS:

- In my code key and secret are hard coded for now and they do work.
- I also tried with "body: JSON.stringify(data)" without success.

Comment: If you want to insert `key` and `secret` into the URL, you need `\`https://${key}:${secret}@...\``  (note the backticks to delimit the string), and provided that the API accepts JSON, you most likely need `body: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: I tried to stringify but it didn't change anything. Question edited accordingly.

Comment: When I try the query string I get `market=BTC-DOGE&quantity=200&price=7.4e-7`; wrapping the price in quotes gives the proper result though. I'd move to postman to figure out the right format first, and once you know exactly how you're supposed to make the request, update this question accordingly.

Comment: Per the [TradeOgre API documentation](https://tradeogre.com/help/api), `/order/buy` is a "POST". Although, strictly speaking, it might be valid" .. and it might even WORK - one shouldn't need a query string with a POST.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710061) and [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html).  "JSON.stringify()" was an excellent suggestion.  Too bad it wasn't the "whole problem" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally succeeded at sending a buy order to the exchange.

Looks like the exchange's API really need to have a content-type declared in the request that is sent. Sending something else than "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or omitting it, leaving fetch or the server find it automatically, returns an invalid market.

It also looks like Fetch doesn't "translate" parameters in JSON format the right way for the API. So we must use parameters in an URL format.

Finally, I had to make the price fixed to 8 decimals as the API refused the amount passed as 74e-8 when converted by javascript. Obviously this must apply to the quantity too when buying fraction of an asset.

Here's the new code:

```
router.get("/submitsell", async (req, res) => {
  const market = "BTC-DOGE"
  const quantity = 200
  const price = (0.00000074).toFixed(8)

  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://{key:secret}@tradeogre.com/api/v1/order/buy', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: 'market=' + market + '&quantity=' + quantity + '&price=' + price,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })
    result = await response.json()
    res.status(200).send(result)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return 0
  }
})
```

Comment: Glad you got it working - thank you for following up.  For whatever it's worth, you *DID* specify a Content-Type: it just wanted a *DIFFERENT* Content-Type.  Neither the [TradeOgre API documentation](https://tradeogre.com/help/api) or any of the (few!) code samples say this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
router.get("/submitsell", async (req, res) => {
   var data = {
      market: "BTC-DOGE",
      quantity: 200,
      price: 0.00000074
   };

   try {
     const response = await fetch('https://{key:secret}@tradeogre.com/api/v1/order/buy', {
        method: 'POST',
        json: data
     });

     result = await response.json()
     res.status(200).send(result)
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return 0;
   }
});
```

Specifying "json" should automagically 1) stringify your payload, 2) add both `Content-type: application/json` and `Content-Length` HTTP headers.

If it still doesn't work, please capture the exact "error" text and copy/paste into your question.

PS: Double-check the API documentation [here](https://tradeogre.com/help/api)